# Project template for Django 1.4+ not creating manage.py

Tags: django

I am using the following project template to generate a django project,
https://bitbucket.org/danjac/django-bootstrap-template

Project layout gets created after I run the following command,
django-admin.py startproject myproject --template=/path/to/django-bootstrap-template/template

But I dont see a manage.py script created. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Your template doesn't have a "manage.py" in it.

Comment: know how to create the same? this is a popular template. I know I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a manage.py, just use the ones from the directory "bin" ...